# Why `tf.tile` propagates gradient through all the copies?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to understand how Tensorflow propagates gradients through functions, concretely `tf.tile`. What I'm trying to do is quite simple:

```py
""" Considering batch_size = 3: """

# CASE 1:

a = tf.constant([[[1., 1.5], [2., 2.5], [3., 3.5]], [[4, 4.5], [5, 5.5], [6, 6.5]], [[7, 7.5], [8., 8.5], [9., 9.5]]])  # shape [3, 3, 2]

b = tf.constant([[[0.1], [0.2], [0.3]], [[0.4], [0.5], [0.6]], [[0.7], [0.8], [0.9]]])  # shape [3, 3, 1]

""" What I want is c = a + b, so I tile b to match last dimension of a: """

b_tile = tf.tile(b, [1, 1, tf.shape(a)[-1]])  # shape [3, 3, 2]
c = a + b_tile  # shape [3, 3, 2]
```

Now let's compute the gradient of `c` with respect to `a` and `b_tile`:

```py
dc_da, dc_dbtile = tf.gradients(c, [a, b_tile])
# dc_da: tensor with same shape as a and all elements 1.
# dc_dbtile: tensor with same shape as b and all elements 1.
```

That makes completely sense, as I have a linear relation: `c = a + b_tile`. However, when I compute the gradient of `b_tile` w.r.t `b`, I expect the gradient to be `1.` too, as I have not changed inner values of `b`, just expand the dimension. But when I do it, it gives `2.` as result:

```py
dbtile_db  = tf.gradients(b_tile, [b])
# dbtile_db: tensor with same shape as b and all elements equal 2.
```

I have also tried concatenating tensor `b` two times instead of using `tf.tile`, and it gives the same result, so it's clear I'm missing something.

I have tried with another example, to check where this comes from. Let's now consider another tensor `t` with exactly the same values as `b` and let's concatenate them to obtain the tensor I need. In that case:

```py
# CASE 2:

m = tf.concat([b, t], -1) # shape [3, 3, 2]. Tensor identical to b_tile
dm_db, dm_dt = tf.gradients(m, [b, t])
# dm_db: tensor with same shape as b and all elements equal 1.
# dm_dt: tensor with same shape as t and all elements equal 1.
```

So I have several questions:

1) What I don't understand is why using `tf.tile`the gradient propagates through all the copies, when they're just a tool to being able to calculate the sum. Numerically, it doesn't make sense to me, I would expect the gradient to propagate as in the last case.

2) What's the difference (in terms of gradients) between case 1 and case 2? Why it should yield to different results when what I'm trying to do is the same?

3) Considering I want to calculate the sum `c = a + b`, what is the correct way?

The problem is that in the example my last dimension is `2` so I can do it manually (the concatenation) buy in my real problem my last dimension is `256000`, so I cannot do it the last way. Thank you in advance